# Yum conflict error after Tuleap install on Centos

Tags: centos, yum, tuleap

I did a basic full install of Tuleap on Centos 6.7 about a month ago. I'm now getting an error `tuleap-plugin-git-gitolite3-4.153-1.el6.noarch has installed conflicts tuleap-plugin-git: tuleap-plugin-git-gitolite3-4.153-1.el6.noarch` and I'm not sure which to remove or reinstall. I'm using the added Epel and the Tuleap repo. It looks like it is conflicting with itself.

Comment: Which command do you run to have this error? What does `rpm -qa | grep tuleap` return?

Answer (score 0):

Found on the Tuleap mailing list:

Add `exclude=php-pecl-apcu` to the `/etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo`
and execute `yum update` again.